# deploying to heroku error "! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

git push heroku master was rejected.  i did some digging in the log and here is what i found.  i have never seen this before.

this was the first thing in the log that looked like it did not go well.  everything before was successful.

```
rake aborted!
   Invalid CSS after "*/": expected identifier, was "/*!"
   (in /tmp/build_2a4aaujom538/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
```

at the very end, the push stops and here is the reason

```
Precompiling assets failed.
Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
[remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:triprecs.git'
```

any ideas on what to check/fix?  thanks

Comment: Perhaps a CSS comment is out of place, leading to invalid CSS in one of your files? To confirm, see if a local run of rake assets:precompile gives you the same error. Then you eliminate heroku as a variable and the problem isolates to the CSS files themselves.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this and no errors showed up.  I've tried getting this site live a couple times, resulting in me creating then deleting heroku apps.  I've done some research and am wondering if this is somehow messing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was i had a comment out of place in one of my css files.  Make sure your CSS files are clean before pushing.  I had an accidental /* in my application.css.erb file which was not commenting anything out.  When i removed it, the push worked!

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is an issue with nested comments being poorly handled by the sass compiler during asset precompilation.

http://www.madflanderz.de/madblog/archives/307/heroku-rake-assetsprecompile-failed-invalid-css/

Removing nested comments in CSS (// lines within /* */ blocks) should solve the issue. This may be harder with third-party CSS libraries you've included in your project. In that case an upgrade of sass-rails could help (but this is something I've never tried).